# generate a mesh of [x,y,z] values using x and y values

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I an trying to generate an array with dimension (w,h,3) there each of the elements is a coordinate [x, y, z] using only set of x, y and z values. The x and y arrays are 1D arrays with shapes (w) and (h) while z is (w,h,1) array. I tried to find a suitable numpy function for this but unsucessfully.
The best solution that I have is:

```
w, h = 6, 4

x = np.tile(np.linspace(-1, 1, w), h).reshape((w,h,-1))
y = np.repeat(np.linspace(-1, 1, h), w).reshape((w,h,-1))
z = np.ones((w, h ,1))
xy = np.dstack((x,y))
xyz = np.dstack((xy,z))
```

but it is supid and I believe that should exist more elegant solution. I will be appreciated for any suggestions

I tried to use meshgrid but looks like i will have 2 separate arrays for X and Y. It will be the same stupid solution as mine

Comment: Since you created 3 (w,h,1) arrays, you can combine them with one concatenate: `np.concatenate((x,y,z),axis=2)` (or one `dstack`)

Comment: You might want to look at the `x` (and `y`) values more carefully.  Your `tile` followed by `reshape` has produced an unexpected layout - at least when compared to other ways of creating a (w,h,1) array.  `np.tile(np.linspace(-1, 1, w)[:,None,None], [1,h,1])`  or `np.repeat(np.linspace(-1, 1, w)[:,None,None], h,1)`

Answer (score 0):

What about [`np.broadcast_arrays`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_arrays.html)?

```
import numpy as np

# Your inputs:
W, H = 6, 4

x = np.arange(W)
y = np.arange(H)
z = np.arange(W * H).reshape(W, H, 1)

# Making sure the arrays broadcast:
xyz = np.dstack(
    np.broadcast_arrays(
        x[:, None, None],   # Shape (W, 1, 1)
        y[:, None],         # Shape    (H, 1)
        z,                  # Shape (W, H, 1)
    )
)
```

Note: [`np.dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) will reshape 2D arrays for you. So if your array `z` starts as `(W, H)`, you can get away with `np.dstack(np.broadcast_arrays(x[:, None], y, z))`